# Slow performance when deleting on a self-joined table

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a MySQL server that receives data from a game via an AJAX handler, and occasionally despite best efforts rows will somehow end up duplicating on-the-fly during the INSERT. I've got a solution that removes them immediately after the INSERTs are done and it was working fine when I only had a few thousand rows in the DB. Now I've got a million rows and during peak time this query takes about 40 seconds to run, and they'll get stacked up as it gets run after every game (peak times right now I get about 3 or 4 new games a minute), and the server doesn't answer any other queries while the delete is running.

```
$removedupes = query("DELETE g1 FROM games g1, games g2 WHERE g1.name=g2.name AND g1.gameno=g2.gameno AND g1.score=g2.score AND g1.id > g2.id AND g1.gameno=".$lastgame);
```

When I EXPLAIN the query it appears that no keys or indices are being used and it's having to check all million+ rows when it only needs to be looking at about 30 at the most.

```
EXPLAIN DELETE g1 FROM games g1, games g2 WHERE g1.name=g2.name AND g1.gameno=g2.gameno AND g1.score=g2.score AND g1.id > g2.id AND g1.gameno=101010
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE g1 ALL PRIMARY,name,name_2,cleanup NULL NULL NULL 1045764 Using where
1 SIMPLE g2 ref PRIMARY,name,name_2,cleanup cleanup 53 dbname.g1.name,const,dbname.g1.score 1 Using where; Using index
```

I've tried doing a select first, but even with forcing new indices to be used the performance is very bad during load. Off-peak times it takes 2-8 seconds to run. I've tried my hand at building a query to put that game into a temp table but I haven't found the right syntax yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your best efforts probably aren't good enough, there's no reason duplicates should appear by magic. And at the very least, an appropriate UNIQUE constraint should prevent them from appearing.

Comment: "Your best efforts probably aren't good enough" Ha, no argument there. I hadn't considered UNIQUE constraints, if I make my columns in question UNIQUE I'll only get a violation if they're all identical at once, correct?

Comment: Yes if you set a unique constraint on all those columns, not one per column.

Comment: You don't seem to have an index on gameno, do you?

Comment: Yeah I was just looking into the syntax there, it looks like it requires no violations first before it'll apply the constraint. That's fair. Gameno is not indexed, correct.

Comment: Well then it's quite normal it has to go through the whole table to find the duplicates...

Comment: I had been kind of scared off of using a lot of indices. "It'll add a lot of RAM usage, it'll have to reindex every time there's an insert." But seeing the performance increase I'm willing to bet this is more than a fair bargain. You've probably solved something here I've been banging my head on longer than I'd care to admit. Thanks for that.

Comment: An index is not reindexed every time there's an insert! It's updated, not reindexed. And an index is not necessarily held in RAM, though it helps if it is.

Comment: @DanielTharp Yeah, I agree with jcaron. A multiple index created as `CREATE INDEX ind_games ON games (gameno, name, id);` would be helpful in making the query more efficient.